# Remove that ?query=keyword from pagination href in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a search input with the `name="keyword"` in form with a `GET` method, that throws me to `?keyword=typed_value`.

Which is absolutely what I want.

But the pagination adds a value to the href:

```
../missions?query=typed_value&keyword=typed_value&page=2
```

instead of

```
../missions?keyword=typed_value&page=2
```

Do you know how to remove that `query=typed_value`, knowing that `typed_value` is the value I typed in the input.

Thanks mates.

Comment: You might want to add some code.  Are you using Laravel's pagination links method?

Comment: Please use backquote (`) instead of single quote (') to quote code.

Comment: @Devon Yes I use laravel's `->paginate(10)` method.